# Why is piping my script's output into the shell's dir command not working as I expected?

Tags: perl, file-io, pipe

I am piping the directory command output to file handle, followed by the print to the file handle. I wish to append some text to the dir/ls output.

```
open (FH, "| dir") or die "$OS_ERROR";
print FH ("sometext") or die "$OS_ERROR";
while (<FH>){
    print;
}
```

When I execute the Perl script, I see the directory contents, but I do not see the text printed using the print statement, in this case I do not see sometext. What am I missing?

To explain in more detail - I want pipe dir contents to FH, and following that I want to append some text to the same filehandle FH . I have referred link http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do. If you did `echo sometext|dir` on the command line, you wouldn't see `sometext` either. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @user1389572, do you want to print the content of the `dir` command output?

Comment: i would to append some text to the dir output and print it using above script. There may be other ways but i am trying example at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to FH with `print` and then expect to read from FH in the next statement. File handles are not FIFOs (by default).
The open gives you a writable file handle, the read end of which is connected to the stdin of `dir`. Reading from a write file handle just gives you nothing.

What do you actually want to achieve? Send some text to the `dir` program, or read output of the `dir` program?

Since in the comment you said you want to read the output of the `dir` command, you have the open command wrong; use `"dir |"` instead of `"| dir"` and read the [Perl Open Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html).

Maybe this does what you want to do:

```
open (FH, "dir|") or die "$OS_ERROR";
while (<FH>){
    print;
}
print "sometext\n";
```

Comment: i want redirect dir contents to FH, and following that also want to write some text to the same filehandle

Comment: Is dir a program producing output or is it a file you want to read? If the former, use `open (FH, "dir |")`, if the latter use `open (FH, "< dir")`. Either way, these are **READ** handles, and you **CANNOT** write to them.

Comment: dir is the program producing output, I am elaborating my requirement -  I want redirect dir contents to FH using command dir or ls, and following that I want to append some text to the same filehandle FH . I have referred link http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens.

Comment: You keep confusing the heck out of everybody: "contents" means "what's in a file". "Output" means "what a running program generates". If `dir` is a program, you read its output, not its contents. If `foo` is a file, you read its contents, not its output.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i wish to pipe dir command output to the filehandle and append some text to the same filehandle. I have referred the first example at the following link http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Pipe-Opens. After executing the above code, I just the dir putput, I do not see text which I wish to append on the console

Answer (score 0):

You are not redirecting anything: You are piping your script's output to either the `cmd.exe` builtin `dir` or an alias to `ls` depending on your OS (which means, you might run into trouble if you run this script with Cygwin's `ls` in your path on Windows).

Writing to `dir` does not seem useful. If you wanted to ***filter*** `dir`s output, i.e. take the output from running `dir` and manipulate it before printing, you should pipe it into your script and you should print the processed output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $pid = open my $dir_out, '-|', 'cmd.exe /c dir';
die "Cannot open pipe: $!\n" unless $pid;

my $output_file = 'output.txt';

open my $my_out, '>', $output_file
    or die "Cannot open '$output_file': $!";

while (my $line = <$dir_out>) {
    $line =~ s/bytes free/peons liberated/;
    print $my_out $line;
}

close $my_out
    or die "Cannot close '$output_file': $!";

close $dir_out 
    or die "Cannot close pipe: $!\n";
```

Of course, I am assuming there are other things going on in your program and this is only a small part of it. Otherwise, you don't need to write this much code for a simple filter.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough just to use `my $out = \`dir\`` for this purpose? Is it better to use pipes to get the output?

Comment: I think the size difference is obvious, but normally it shouldn't be an issue while most of the outputs are several hunders of bytes (until you have something like `man gcc`). Just was curious about the method outside the speed or memory footprint.

Comment: ok, I want pipe dir contents to FH using command dir or ls, and following that I want to append some text to the same filehandle FH